# Php Mailer - continue with next mail if sent() error occurs

Tags: php, phpmailer, bulk-mail

I am new to use phpmailer for sending bulk mails.
The execution stops and shows error if send() fails.

Is there any way to skip the error and continue with next email id.
I am using email id's from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Catch Exception Mechanism, to continue with next Mail with appropriate logic

Posted by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284364/phil-rykoff)
PHPMAiler uses Exceptions. Try to adopt the following

```
require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use `phplist` for bulk mailing with PHP mailer or without
[click Here](http://www.phplist.com/) for more

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can suppress error display by adding **@** to the function. This will usually prevent the error from being displayed. 
 
For your situation, you can put the code in **try..catch**. In the **catch** section, check if the all the emails have been sent; if not, just continue with the next one. This also means that you need a way to track the total emails and the number of emails completed. 
 
Hope this helps.